# Matlab fill contour3 plot like contourf plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I'd like to fill a 3D contour plot (`contour3(X,Y,Z)`) like the 2D contour fill plot (`contourf(X,Y,Z)`). But I can't figure out how this can be achieved. The combination of contour3 and surf is not very satisfying, since there are tiles.

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(32);

figure
contourf(X,Y,Z,15);

figure
contour3(X,Y,Z,15,'k');
hold on;
surf(X,Y,Z, 'Edgecolor', 'none');
```

`contourf(X,Y,Z,15);`
[image]

`contour3(X,Y,Z,15,'k'); hold on; surf(X,Y,Z, 'Edgecolor', 'none');`
[image]

Comment: `shading interp` should make that prettier already.

Comment: This removes the tiles but now the color gradient is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by the "color gradient" is the problem ?

Comment: Between two contour lines should only be one color and this color should differ from the color in the adjacent area, like in the `contourf` plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the colour on a basic surface plot is function of the `Z` data. they will either be faceted or interpolated but the `contour3` function will not modify the colouring of the `surf` object. The `contour3` function only draws the isolines.

If you want your `surface` to be coloured in a "blocky" way like a flat colour plot, you have to make the colormap "blocky" as well:
In your example you use `15` isolines, so you have to create a colormap with `15+1` colour so each colour block of the colormap match an isoline.

```
nContour = 15 ;
figure ; [X,Y,Z] = peaks(32);
surf(X,Y,Z, 'Edgecolor', 'none');
shading interp
colormap( parula(nContour+1) ) %// assign a colormap with only 15+1 colors
```

Will get you the image on the left of the screenshot below. Now add your isolines on top if you want:

```
hold on;
[C,h] = contour3(X,Y,Z,nContour,'k');
```

and you get the plot on the right. You can do both these things in no particular order, just make sure the colormap of the surface is adequate for the number of isolines you want.

[image: contour3ex]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You are probably rendering with OpenGL.
In order to avoid color jumping more than one adjacent value between contour lines, you need to modify the renderer to Painters:

```
set (gcf,'Renderer','painters')
```

Hope that helps!